# When i run my program my thread is working but images are not setting for the grid can someone give a solution for this.

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

**ISymbol interface**

```
package main;

import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public interface ISymbol {

    void setImage(String location,String name);
    Image getImage();
    void setValue(int value);
    int getValue();

}
```

**Symbol class**

```
package main;

import javafx.scene.image.Image;

import java.io.File;

public class Symbol implements ISymbol {

    Image image;
    int value;

    @Override
    public void setImage(String location,String name) {
        File file = new File(location);
        image = new Image(file.toURI().toString(),100,100,true,true);

    }

    @Override
    public Image getImage() {
        return image;

    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;

    }

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return value;

    }

}
```

In here i'm trying to add images randomly to a array and i'm using that array in my main class to add those images to my reels

**Reel class**

```
package main;

import java.util.Random;

public class Reel {

   public Symbol[] spin(){

        Symbol cherry = new Symbol();
        Symbol redSeven = new Symbol();
        Symbol watermelon = new Symbol();
        Symbol bell  = new Symbol();
        Symbol lemon = new Symbol();
        Symbol plum = new Symbol();

        Random random = new Random();

        Symbol[] symbolArray = new Symbol[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < symbolArray.length; i++) {
            int randomNumber = random.nextInt(6);
            System.out.println(randomNumber);
            switch (randomNumber) {
                case 0:
                    cherry.setValue(2);
                    cherry.setImage("/images/cherry.png","cherry");
                    symbolArray[i] = cherry;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    lemon.setValue(3);
                    lemon.setImage("/images/lemon.png","lemon");
                    symbolArray[i] = lemon;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    plum.setValue(4);
                    plum.setImage("/images/plum.png","plum");
                    symbolArray[i] = plum;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    watermelon.setValue(5);
                    watermelon.setImage("/images/watermelon.png", "watermelon");
                    symbolArray[i] = watermelon;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    bell.setValue(6);
                    bell.setImage("/images/bell.png", "bell");
                    symbolArray[i] = bell;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    redSeven.setValue(7);
                    redSeven.setImage("images/redseven.png","seven");
                    symbolArray[i] = redSeven;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        return symbolArray;

    }


}
```

This is my main class that include all methods. In the btnSpin method i'm calling my thread and for setting images for the reels i have used a reel method 
I have debug my program and checked whether the image is coming the image was on there but when i set my image to the image view it wont work while i'm running my thread those imageviews are disappeared can someone give me a solution waiting for a reply thank you :)

**SlotMachine class**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.Reflection;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import main.Reel;
import main.Symbol;


public class SlotMachine extends Application implements Runnable {

    //creating a thread
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
        @Override public void run(){
            reel1();
        }
    };

    //default image for reel
    private Image image = new Image("/images/icon.png");

    //UI variables
    private  Text title;
    private  Label lblStatus,lblInformationArea, lblBetAmount, lblCreditArea;
    private  ImageView image1, image2, image3;
    private  Button btnSpin, btnAddCoin, btnBetOne, btnBetMax, btnReset, btnStatistics;


    //calculation variables
    private  int remainingCoins = 10;
    private  int betAmount, wins, lost, reel1value, reel2value, reel3value;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0));
        grid.setHgap(20);
        grid.setVgap(20);
        grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);

        // Title in row 0 column 3 with styling
        title = new Text();
        title.setCache(true);
        title.setText("REEL RUSH");
        title.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        title.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 60));
        Reflection r = new Reflection();
        title.setEffect(r);
        GridPane.setConstraints(title, 3, 1);
        GridPane.setHalignment(title, HPos.CENTER);

        // Reel1 in row 4 column 2
        image1 = new ImageView(image);
        GridPane.setConstraints(image1, 2, 4);
        GridPane.setHalignment(image1, HPos.CENTER);

        // Reel2 in row 4 column 3
        image2 = new ImageView(image);
        GridPane.setConstraints(image2, 3, 4);
        GridPane.setHalignment(image2, HPos.CENTER);

        // Reel3 in row 4 column 4
        image3 = new ImageView(image);
        GridPane.setConstraints(image3, 4, 4);
        GridPane.setHalignment(image3, HPos.CENTER);

        // adding mouse click event for image views
        image1.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event) {
                symbolClicked(event);
                System.out.println("REEL 1 IS CLICKED");
            }
        });

        image2.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event) {
                symbolClicked(event);
                System.out.println("REEL 2 IS CLICKED");
            }
        });

        image3.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event) {
                symbolClicked(event);
                System.out.println("REEL 3 IS CLICKED");
            }
        });

        // Status label row 8 column 4
        lblStatus = new Label("YOU LOOSE");
        lblStatus.setId("label-lblStatus");
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblStatus, 3, 8);
        GridPane.setHalignment(lblStatus, HPos.CENTER);

        //information area label row 9 column 3
        lblInformationArea = new Label("INFORMATION AREA ");
        lblInformationArea.setId("label-lbl");
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblInformationArea, 3, 9);
        GridPane.setHalignment(lblInformationArea, HPos.CENTER);

        // Credit area label row 5 column 2
        lblCreditArea = new Label("CREDIT AREA: " + remainingCoins);
        lblCreditArea.setId("label-lbl");
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblCreditArea, 2, 9);
        GridPane.setHalignment(lblCreditArea, HPos.CENTER);

        // Bet amount label row 5 column 4
        lblBetAmount = new Label("BET AMOUNT: " +betAmount);
        lblBetAmount.setId("label-lbl");
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblBetAmount, 4, 9);
        GridPane.setHalignment(lblBetAmount, HPos.CENTER);

        // Add coin button row 6 column 3
        btnSpin = new Button("SPIN");
        btnSpin.setId("button-btnSpin");
        GridPane.setConstraints(btnSpin, 3, 10);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btnSpin, HPos.CENTER);

        // Add coin button row 8 column 1
        btnAddCoin = new Button("ADD COIN");
        GridPane.setConstraints(btnAddCoin, 2, 12);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btnAddCoin, HPos.CENTER);

        // Add coin button row 8 column 2
        btnBetOne = new Button("BET ONE");
        btnBetOne.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 20));
        GridPane.setConstraints(btnBetOne, 1, 12);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btnBetOne, HPos.CENTER);

        // Add coin button row 8 column 3
        btnBetMax = new Button("BET MAX");
        GridPane.setConstraints(btnBetMax, 4, 12);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btnBetMax, HPos.CENTER);

        // Add coin button row 8 column 4
        btnReset = new Button("RESET");
        GridPane.setConstraints(btnReset, 6, 12);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btnReset, HPos.CENTER);

        // Add coin button row 8 column 5
        btnStatistics = new Button("STATISTICS");
        GridPane.setConstraints(btnStatistics, 3, 12);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btnStatistics, HPos.CENTER);



        // -------------------  Adding mouse events for each button  ---------------------------

        btnAddCoin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
                remainingCoins++;
                lblCreditArea.setText("CREDIT AREA: "+remainingCoins);
            }
        });

        btnBetOne.setOnAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
                if (remainingCoins > 0) {
                    remainingCoins--;
                    betAmount++;
                    lblBetAmount.setText("BET AMOUNT: " + betAmount);

                    lblCreditArea.setText("CREDIT AREA: " + remainingCoins);
                } else {
                    lblInformationArea.setText("No Credits Left!!!! Please Insert A Coin");
                }
            }
        });

        btnSpin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
                if (betAmount > 0) {
                    System.out.println("SPIN BUTTON CLICKED");
                    thread1.start();
                } else {
                    lblInformationArea.setText("You did not bet!!!! Please Bet");
                }
            }
        });
        btnReset.setOnAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
                remainingCoins = 10;
                betAmount = 0;
                lblBetAmount.setText("BET AMOUNT: " + betAmount);

                lblCreditArea.setText("CREDIT AREA: " + remainingCoins);
                lblInformationArea.setText("Status");
                image1.setImage(image);
                image2.setImage(image);
                image3.setImage(image);
            }

        });

        btnBetMax.setOnAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
                if (remainingCoins >= 3) {
                    remainingCoins = remainingCoins - 3;
                    betAmount = betAmount + 3;
                    lblBetAmount.setText("BET AMOUNT: " + betAmount);

                    lblCreditArea.setText("CREDIT AREA: " + remainingCoins);

                } else {
                    lblInformationArea.setText("No Credits Left!!!! Please Insert A Coin");
                }
            }
        });

        btnStatistics.setOnAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {

                //statistic();
                lblInformationArea.setText("Spin the Reel First");
            }
        });

        // adding all to the scene
        grid.getChildren().addAll(title, lblStatus, lblInformationArea, lblCreditArea, lblBetAmount, btnAddCoin, btnBetMax, btnBetOne, btnReset, btnSpin, btnStatistics, image1, image3 , image2);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 1450, 920);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/css/main.css");
        primaryStage.setTitle("REEL RUSH");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public  void reel1() {
        while (true) {
            //creating reel objects for each reel
            Reel firstReel = new Reel();
            Reel secondReel = new Reel();
            Reel thirdReel = new Reel();

            Symbol[] firstReelSymbols = firstReel.spin();
            Symbol[] secondReelSymbols = secondReel.spin();
            Symbol[] thirdReelSymbols = thirdReel.spin();

            for (Symbol item : firstReelSymbols) {
                Image img1 = item.getImage();
                image1.setImage(img1);
                reel1value = item.getValue();
            }

            for (Symbol item : secondReelSymbols) {
                Image img1 = item.getImage();
                image2.setImage(img1);
                reel1value = item.getValue();
            }

            for (Symbol item : thirdReelSymbols) {
                Image img1 = item.getImage();
                image3.setImage(img1);
                reel1value = item.getValue();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void symbolClicked(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event) {

        //TODO stop thread when image clicked

        if((reel1value==reel3value)&&(reel2value==reel3value)){
            //check if all 3 numbers are same
            lblInformationArea.setText("You Win");
            remainingCoins+=(betAmount*reel1value);
            lblCreditArea.setText("Credits Area: "+remainingCoins);
            wins++;

        }else{
            lblInformationArea.setText("You Loose");

            lost++;
        }
        betAmount=0;
        lblBetAmount.setText("Bet Amount: "+betAmount);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            launch(args);
        }

    }
```

Comment: From [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--): *"It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution."* You are making no attempt to prevent the user from clicking the button again though and you aren't replacing `thread1` or disabling the button. Expect this to result in exceptions for users not knowing they must not click the button more than once.Also there is a LOT of code not necessary to reproduce the problem.Please create a [MCVE] instead of dumping your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, while you can "run" an `Application`, we would never implement `Runnable` in an `Application`. JavaFX will do its own application management, and there is no way you can "run" an application in another thread.

Now, back to your question. Your `reel1()` is badly written. If you know a particular method is going to run in non-UI thread (i.e. JavaFX Application thread), you must take note not to directly set any kind of value that changes the UI within it.

So, this:

```
for (Symbol item : firstReelSymbols) {
    Image img1 = item.getImage();
    image1.setImage(img1);
    reel1value = item.getValue();
}
```

should becomes something like:

```
for (Symbol item : firstReelSymbols) {
    Image img1 = item.getImage();
    Platform.runLater(() -> image1.setImage(img1)); // Run this run on UI thread
    reel1value = item.getValue(); // Not sure what this value is for, may need to be wrapped inside Platform.runLater() if it affects UI
}
```

Other than this, it is weird that you are looping through a list of `Symbol` objects, and inside the loop you are setting the same `image1` field.

Comment: Thank you for replying. variable img1 is within the for loop so it wont matter i think so. That reel1value variable is for comparing to check user if he win or not. What should i replace for Symbol objects? I have corrected my code but still i cant figure how to add a thread and how to stop them if can can you give me a solution for that